# Static fragment over ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to develope a Walkthroughs that looks like skillpages app, but I don't know how to put a static fragment  with buttons a ViewPager creating the filling of button flotating over the image, someone can help me please

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 0):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html with transparent background.Position the popup window at the bottom of the screen.

Have a look at this code:https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard
It uses popupwindow to display emoticons keyboard.

Comment: Thx!! @RupeshJain I'll see how to implent that soluction and for sure I'll publicate the result soon :)

Comment: other option is keep a single fragment and listen for swipe gesture..when  user swipes left or right just change the background of the view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ViewPager 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Karakuri, actually , I used this as my first option but the image of viewPager stays over the button and not in the background